# how to use material 3 searchbar from xml

Tags: android, searchbar, material3

I want to use material 3 searchbar in my kotlin app, I can't figure out how to put and get the text in searchbar, when I click on it, it behaves like a button (shows ripples) but can't put text in it

```
<com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/navigationbarcolor"
    android:hint="Search" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Material 3 Search Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75996550/material-3-search-bar)

Comment: No and can't ask them if they have solved the thing in comment, because I need 50 reputations to comment